# How to read a string input containing spaces using Scanner and print it out in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can I accept the string as input in Java from the user by using the `Scanner` class that includes spaces and printing the accepted input with spaces?

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double j=scan.nextDouble();
        String k=scan.next.split(' ');

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + k);
        System.out.println("Double: " + j);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

This is a--input
This is a--output

Comment: Formatting required. 1) Shorten your title. 2) Add the details inside along the code. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how your code does anything similar to what your question is asking.  It seems all it is asking you to do is use `nextLine` and print the line?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what problem you are experiencing, but I advise you to read all strings like this:

```
String myString = scan.nextLine();
```

If you want to split it on every space, then just do it like this:

```
String[] mySplitString = myString.split(" ");
```

Note that the method above accepts a string variable and not a char variable. You have to store split strings into an array of strings (String[]), because the split method will generate one or multiple strings, depending on how many spaces there are in an input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nextLine() function of Scanner Class. 
Like this:-

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine();   //for getting input
System.out.print(str);  //for Printing
```

Hope this will help you.